# Javascript: Not picking up my "src"

Tags: javascript, html, var

```
<input class="textBox" id="userWebsite" type="text" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="Store" onclick="submit();"/> 

<!-- Storage START -->
<select id="webLinks">
  <option id="webPageOne">Web Page One</option>
  <option id="webPageTwo">http://www.example.com</option>
  <option id="webPageThree">http://www.example.com</option>
  <option id="webPageFour">http://www.example.com</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Goto" onclick="goto();"/> 
<!-- Storage END -->

<iframe src="http://www.freedom.tm/dashboard" id="iframe"></iframe>
<!-- Default Promotor END -->


<script>
    var userWebsite = document.getElementById('userWebsite');
    function submit() {
        document.getElementById("webPageOne").innerHTML = userWebsite.value;
    }

    var webPageOne = document.getElementById('webPageOne');

    function goto() {
        document.getElementById("iframe").src = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
    }
</script>
```

Ok, currently the problem is the end part

```
    function goto() {
        document.getElementById("iframe").src = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
    }
```

I was wondering why it isn't picking up the option that's selected. For example, if webpage two is selected, Why it doesn't select the website selected and change the source to what ever website two is set as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a js error, edit following function

```
function goto() {
    document.getElementById("iframe").src = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[1].value;
}
```

or common approach

```
 function goto() {
        document.getElementById("iframe").src = document.getElementById('webLinks').options[document.getElementById('webLinks').selectedIndex].text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function goto() {
    document.getElementById("iframe").src = document.getElementById('webLinks').options[document.getElementById('webLinks').selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Comment: You're an absolute god!